# How to find correlation between different tests in the same sample?

Tags: statistics, correlation, sampling

I did several tests in a sample of 90 individuals to check some behaviors. I got the following results:

10% of my sample has the behavior A
65% of my sample has the behavior B
80% of my sample has the behavior C

Now I want to know what is the percentage of individuals that behave like A or B or C. Is there any way to find out the answer or is that impossible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible if you have no information about the correlation of A B and C between each other.

Imagine the case every person with behavior A has also behavior B, and everyone with behavior B has behavior C. Then exactly 80% of people have behaviors A B or C.

An other case would be if every person can either have behavior A or B but not both. Then at least 90% of the people have behavior A B or C.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you very much.